# how to use reference id ( # ) in ngFor and get focus next Ng select?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I have loop ngFor and i need to declare reference id '#' with the index .For eg

```
<button (click)="addRow()"></button>
<tr *ngFor="let data of datas; let i= index">
<td><ng-select #data{{i}} ></ng-select></td>
</tr>
```

```
addRow(){
// after selected data next row to focus.
}
```

and i want to focus to next row of ng-select.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you describe the behavior you want? When do you want to focus the next row?

Comment: did u get problems ? i have added some changes.

Comment: why the array and an array of object name same?

Comment: sorry ! its pseudo code i forget to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** Viewchildren a input or a ng-select

with a input you can use ViewChildren

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
      <input #data/>
</div>

@ViewChildren('data') data: QueryList<ElementRef>;
ngAfterViewInit()
{
    this.data.changes.subscribe(()=>{
       this.data.last.nativeElement.focus();
    })
}
```

If we has a ng-select you need

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <ng-select #data .....>
   </ng-select> 
</div>

<!--see that the "QueryList" is a NgSelectComponent-->
@ViewChildren('data') data: QueryList<NgSelectComponent>;
ngAfterViewInit()
    {
        this.data.changes.subscribe(()=>{
          <!--we use filterInput.nativeElement-->
          this.data.last.filterInput.nativeElement.focus();
        })
    }
```

A [full stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-slq5kg?file=app/app.component.ts) (In the stackblitz I add a "takeWhile" to unsubscribe changes in a ngOnDestroy the element)

Comment: Don't forget unsubscribe (I update my answer adding a stackblitz)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code

```
<tr *ngFor="let dataObject of data; let i = index; trackBy:i;">
  <td><ng-select #data{{i}} ></ng-select></td>
</tr>
```

**For Focusing**

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
... 

@ViewChild('data1') inputEl:ElementRef;

addRow() {
  setTimeout(() => this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus());
}
```

**Or**

```
import Renderer2 from @angular/core into your component. Then:

const element = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#data1');

setTimeout(() => element.focus(), 0);
```

Referrence https://coderanch.com/t/675897/languages/programmatically-manage-focus-Angular-app

Comment: will i able to focus select ?